# is a correct_user before action here necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, users and common_app.

Users has_one common_app.

In the common_app controller, I define almost everything using the current_user helper. This essentially makes it so that the edit forms ignore the id that the user POSTs via the web browser.

It looks like so -->

```
class CommonAppsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def new
    if current_user.common_app.present?
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @common_app = current_user.build_common_app
    end
  end

  def create 
    @common_app = current_user.build_common_app(common_app_params)
    if @common_app.save
        flash[:success] = "Common App Created!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        redirect_to 'common_apps/new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if current_user.common_app.update_attributes(common_app_params)
      flash[:success] = "Common App Updated"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'common_apps/edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @common_app = current_user.common_app
  end

  def edit
    @common_app = current_user.common_app
  end

  private

    def common_app_params
      params.require(:common_app).permit(:current_city,:grad_year,:read_type,
                                          :listen_speak,:time_in_china,
                                          :cover_letter,:resume) ####fill in the correct ones here
    end

    # is correct_user necessary?
end
```

What makes me wary though is that I am not using a correct_user before action. If I were to not use it, would there be a security hole here? I.e could someone POST through a shell or something?

If yes, how would you change the controller, to include the before filter?

PS: I'm also a bit confused about the correct use of @ variables. If I am overusing them, or doing something wacky with them, please let me know and help me become a better noob :)

PPS: This is my SessionsHelper Module, for the signed_in_user before filter to work -- >

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default) # this creates friendly forwarding for the app
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: Is your `:signed_in_user` filter defined somewhere else? In `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Hi Janfoeh, signed_in_user is defined under SessionsHelper, let me update that -->

Comment: What would a `correct_user` filter do? What do you suspect might be missing here?

Comment: I'm having a noob suspicion, that there may be a way to access someone else's common_app, and edit it. This is a fairly simple app, and I'm sure no one would want to do it, but still want to make sure that a hacker of some sorts would not be able to update or see someone else's common_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any security problem here. Even without the `before_action :signed_in_user`, since you always go through the `current_user.common_app` association, if a user where not signed in, the action would simply fail.

So the controller is sound. As long as your authentication system has no flaws, the controller itself exposes no weakness.

In Ruby, variables prefixed with '@' are instance variables. In the context of a Rails controller, the distinction is simple:

Use instance variables for values you want to make available to your view, and normal variables for everything else.